# Using Google Admin SDK in Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to create some small apps that will add/remove/change users in a Google Apps for Business Domain (test-version)

I've been fiddeling aroound with Python2.7 on Windows 7, and downloaded google-api-python-client-1.1 but it's not working. I get various errors. I'm not a skilled python programmer, but it seems as if the samples are yousing som depreciated methods (calling non-existant API Service name aso)

I've also checked GAM by DITO , but the sourcecode I Found wont run, not even after trying to correct the more obvious errors.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: GAM works fine for many users. You need to show code if you want help...

Comment: True. My bad! 
The samplecode I try to run is from the google-api-python-client-samples-1.1

Comment: Another try: 
My bad! 
I try code from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-python-client-samples-1.1.zip (groupssetting-sample)
when running :
python groupsettings.py --groupId='ledning@bergstedts.mygbiz.com' --whoCanViewMembers=ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW
I get:
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\apiclient\http.py", line 680, in execute
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/%27ledning@bergst
edts.mygbiz.com%27?alt=json returned "Access Not Configured">

Comment: rather than trying to put code in a comment, please edit your original question. It sounds like you didn't turn Groups Settings API on for your API project in the console.